# show selected accounts on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

i have is_active__C checkbox on account object. so my requirment is on visualforce page i want to take one check box as 'show active accounts only'.when ever its checked i want to show active accounts only(which account checked while creating account record).otherwise show all accounts

i wrote dis
PAGE

```
       <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accountList}" var="wrapRec" rendered="{!selectedList}">
           <apex:column value="{!wrapRec.Name}" />
           <apex:column value="{!wrapRec.Id}"/>               
      </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:outputPanel>      
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class accountExtension{
    public List<Account> accountList{get;set;}
    public accountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        accountList = [SELECT id ,Name FROM Account];
    }
    public boolean activeAccountOnly{get;set;}
    public void showActiveAccounts(){
        accountList = new List<myWrapperClass>();
        normalList = false;
        selectedList = true;
        if(activeAccountOnly == false)
        {
            accountList = [SELECT id ,Name FROM Account WHERE is_active__C =TRUE];
        }else{
            accountList = [SELECT id ,Name FROM Account];
        }
    }
}
```

> error illage assignmntand compie err

Comment: Can you provide what you have so far? From reading your description I'm sure the community would be able to help but this is a community to answer questions and help with your code if you don't provide anything its very hard for the community to answer (we're not going to write the code for you)

Comment: on vf page i created one chekbok with name show active accounts and have one command button get accounts. if the chekbox is checked i want to show only active accounts

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Praveen. Are you asking about a List View? If not, please post your code to show us what you've done so far or this question will be closed. If you need help learning the Salesforce Platform, I recommend the following resources [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide].(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).tform,  Suggest you also visit the [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works.

Comment: Please provide full code, so that community helps you. I think that solution provided by Samuel is good.

Comment: Try replacing `accountList = new List<myWrapperClass>();` this to `accountList = new List<Account>();`

Answer (score 1):

It always helps when you include on what line the error is, or mark that in your code. But, i'm going to assume it's the following:

```
 public List<Account> accountList{get;set;}
 ...
 accountList = new List<myWrapperClass>();
```

You've declared it as type `List<Account>`, this means you CAN NOT assign another type list to it, yet that is what you're doing. You either have to declare it differently, or assign it correctly.